# Strange behaviour of Meteor.collection.find()

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I stuck with strange behaviour in meteor -> iron router

```
this.route('addItem', {
        path: '/additem/:_owner',
        action: function(){
            var c = Presentation.find().count();
            var id = Presentation.insert({
                owner: this.params._owner,
                order: c
            });
            this.redirect('editItem', {_id: id});
        }

this.route('editItem', {
        path: '/edititem/:_id',
        data: function(){return Presentation.findOne(this.params._id)}
    });
```

in this case, data is empty, but if c is const (var c = 1), all works correctly:

```
this.route('addItem', {
        path: '/additem/:_owner',
        action: function(){
            var c = 1;
            var id = Presentation.insert({
                owner: this.params._owner,
                order: c
            });
            this.redirect('editItem', {_id: id});
        }

this.route('editItem', {
        path: '/edititem/:_id',
        data: function(){return Presentation.findOne(this.params._id)}
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give you a race condition? If it's just for ordering, why don't you use a timestamp?

Comment: Further explain what's happening when the collection is empty.

Comment: why its give a race condition? I dont use timestamp, because order may be changed later by user.

Answer (score 0):

Presentation is a collection on the client.  It could have nothing in it, that Collection will get synched with whatever the server is setup to publish at some point, it will reactively update things that depend on it when synched, however in a route you are just assuming its synched, which is highly unlikely.  You can put a waiton in your route.  Or use a Meteor method, or do a server side route.

Answer (score 0):

solved with Meteor metod, but not understood (

next code shows in console rigth vsriables, but data empty.

```
this.route('addItem', {
        path: '/additem/:_owner',
        action: function(){
            var c = Presentation.find().count();
            console.log('c: '+c);
            var id = Presentation.insert({
                owner: this.params._owner,
                order: c
            });
            this.redirect('editItem', {_id: id});
        }

this.route('editItem', {
        path: '/edititem/:_id',
        data: function(){console.log('doc: ' + Presentation.findOne(this.params._id)); 
                         return Presentation.findOne(this.params._id)}
    });
```